# How to programmatically create a dropdown of users of role x

Tags: 7, database

I have a question for you guys: how can I programmatically create a dropdown of users of role x to use as a filter on a view? I'm am pretty new to Drupal, but I think this requires a db_query.

I've experimented with a field called 'hosting provider', but this doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
<?php

function dd_hosting_provider_form_views_exposed_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {
  $field_id = 'field_hosting_provider';
  // Only alter forms with the necessary field
  //if (isset($form[$field_id .'_value'])) {
    // Build a query to get all node ids having the specified field
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query = db_select('users', 'u')
                ->fields('u', array('uid', 'name',))
                ->condition('ur.rid', array(8),'IN') // 8 is the rid for Developer.
                ->groupBy('u.uid');
    $query->innerJoin('users_roles', 'ur', 'u.uid = ur.uid');
    $results = $query->execute();
    var_dump($results);exit();

    // Attach the field values to the nodes
    $nodes = $results['node'];
    field_attach_load('node', $nodes, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $field_id));

    // Add a default so the filter is optional
    $options = array('' => ' - Any - ');

    // Buld the options array based on the query results, overwriting duplicate entries
    foreach($nodes as $nid => $node) {
      $value = $node->field_primary_dev['und'][0]['target_id'];
      $options[$value] = $value;
   //}

    // Alter the field
    $form[$field_id .'_value']['#type'] = 'select';
    $form[$field_id .'_value']['#options'] = $options;
    $form[$field_id .'_value']['#size'] = 1;
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to create a view's filter programmatically, since this can be done easily via the view's UI ? If that's not the case however you have to go with a views custom handler, `form_alter` won't help.